# rails+rspec controller spec with polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to test the actions in controller spec but for some reason I get the no routes matches error. What should I do to make the route work?

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"create", :comment=>{:body=>"Consectetur quo accusamus ea.", 
   :commentable=>"4"}, :controller=>"comments", :post_id=>"4"}
```

model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true, touch: true 

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
```

routes

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments, only: [:create, :update, :destroy], module: :posts
end
```

controller_spec

```
describe "POST create" do
  let!(:user) { create(:user) }
  let!(:profile) { create(:profile, user: @user) }
  let!(:commentable) { create(:post, user: @user) }

  context "with valid attributes" do
    subject(:create_action) { xhr :post, :create, post_id: commentable, comment: attributes_for(:comment, commentable: commentable, user: @user) }

    it "saves the new task in the db" do
      expect{ create_action }.to change{ Comment.count }.by(1)
    end
    ...
```

EDIT

The controller_spec from above can be found in `spec/controllers/comments_controller_spec.rb`

controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
    authorize @comment
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      @comment.send_comment_creation_notification(@commentable)
      respond_to :js
    end
  end
```

controllers/posts/comments_controller.rb

```
  class Posts::CommentsController < CommentsController
    before_action :set_commentable

    private

    def set_commentable
      @commentable = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `module: :posts` will route to `Posts::CommentsController#create`.

If that is not what you intended than remove the module option.

Otherwise you need to ensure that you have the correct class name for both your controller and spec.

```
class Posts::CommentsController
  def create

  end
end

RSpec.describe Posts::CommentsController do
  # ...
end
```

Also note that if often does not make sense to nest the "individual actions" for a resource.

Instead you may want to declare the routes like so:

```
resources :comments, only: [:update, :destroy] # show, edit ...

resources :posts do
  resources :comments, only: [:create], module: :posts # new, index
end
```

Which gives you:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_posts

  # DELETE /comments/:id
  def destroy
     # ...
  end

  # PUT|PATCH /comments/:id
  def update
  end
end 

class Posts::CommentsController < ApplicationController
  # POST /posts/:post_id/comments
  def create
     # ...
  end
end
```

See [Avoid Deeply Nested Routes in Rails](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-shallow-nesting/) for a deeper explaination of why.

---

Setting the up the controller to use inheritance in this case is a good idea - however you cannot test the `create` method through the parent `CommentsController` class in a controller spec since RSpec will always look at `described_class` when trying to resolve the route.

Instead you may want to use shared examples:

```
# /spec/support/shared_examples/comments.rb
RSpec.shared_examples "nested comments controller" do |parameter|
  describe "POST create" do
    let!(:user) { create(:user) }

    context "with valid attributes" do
      subject(:create_action) { xhr :post, :create, post_id: commentable, comment: attributes_for(:comment, commentable: commentable, user: @user) }

      it "saves the new task in the db" do
        expect{ create_action }.to change{ Comment.count }.by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'shared_examples/comments'
RSpec.describe Posts::CommentsController
  # ...
  include_examples "nested comments controller" do
    let(:commentable) { create(:post, ...) }
  end
end
```

---

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'shared_examples/comments'
RSpec.describe Products::CommentsController
  # ...
  include_examples "nested comments controller" do
    let(:commentable) { create(:product, ...) }
  end
end
```

The other alternative which I prefer is to use request specs instead:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe "Comments", type: :request do

  RSpec.shared_example "has nested comments" do
    let(:path) { polymorphic_path(commentable) + "/comments" } 
    let(:params) { attributes_for(:comment) }

    describe "POST create" do
      expect do
        xhr :post, path, params
      end.to change(commentable.comments, :count).by(1)
    end
  end


  context "Posts" do
     include_examples "has nested comments" do
       let(:commentable) { create(:post) }
     end
  end

  context "Products" do
     include_examples "has nested comments" do
       let(:commentable) { create(:product) }
     end
  end
end
```

Since you are really sending a HTTP request instead of faking it they cover more of the application stack. This does however come with a small price in terms of test speed. Both shared_context and [shared_examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples) are two of the things which make RSpec really awesome.

Comment: max, u are right, my routes could be used without nesting for update/destroy. I updated my answer with my create action setup. I'd keep the comment creation code in `CommentsController` instead of `Posts::CommentsController` as u can see in the updated question. I also  have product comments, so this way it's enough to put `set_post` or `set_product` in the module controllers and I can keep the main part of the create action in the `CommentsController`. What do you think? Can you tell me how I can test this if I have half of the code here and half there? Btw. in dev env everything works fine.

Comment: max, pls also see my prev comment. So I just nested my controller spec as you advised for create action and it worked out. THX

Comment: Nice that it worked out - see my edit for some tips on how to test it.

Comment: I didn't figured out that i should create the same namespace for my tests like for controllers.